# Pulp Solver constraint

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am create a LP Solver using PULP to get minimize the cost. I wanted to add an upper bound value to skip some of the results.

```
costs = dict(zip(Variety_items,tempdf['cost']))
Bright = dict(zip(Variety_items,tempdf['Bright']))
Colour = dict(zip(Variety_items,tempdf['colour']))
Thickness = dict(zip(Variety_items,tempdf['Thickness']))

prob = LpProblem("Problem", LpMinimize)

Variety_items_var = LpVariable.dicts("B",Variety_items,0)
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*Variety_items_var[i] for i in Variety_items])
prob += lpSum([Variety_items_var[i] for i in Variety_items]) == 1, "PercentagesSum"
prob += lpSum([Bright[i] * Variety_items_var[i] for i in Variety_items]) == 40, "C1"
prob += lpSum([Colour[i] * Variety_items_var[i] for i in Variety_items]) == 90, "C2"
prob += lpSum([Thickness[i] * Variety_items_var[i] for i in Variety_items]) <= 15, "C3"

prob.solve()
```

Below is the result combination with 101.40471619 as the best cost.
Help required is : minimum should be 0.07 and I am getting 0.03 in the result which I would like to add as constraint

```
B_XXX_1 = 0.0
B_XXX_14 = 0.0
B_XXX_16 = 0.21351179
B_XXX_2 = 0.0
B_XXX_3 = 0.14404079
B_XXX_4 = 0.0
B_XXX_5 = 0.0
B_XXX_6 = 0.0
B_DX_15 = 0.6042065
B_DX_17 = 0.0
B_DX_7 = 0.0
B_DX_8 = 0.0
B_DP_11 = 0.0
B_DP_12 = 0.0
B_DP_13 = 0.038240918
B_TX_10 = 0.0
B_TX_9 = 0.0
```

Note : I have not attached full code. its Pandas DF to dict converted.

Comment: The meaning of your post is obscured due to inconsistent usage of language. If English is not your native language, perhaps an automated translator might help. If my understanding that your goal is to ensure every nonzero coefficient B_zzz_ is greater than 0.07 is correct then I am afraid this cannot be expressed as a linear constraint.

Comment: Yes @DmitriChubarov, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want x to be 0 or between the constants L and U. Introduce a binary variable d and the constraint

```
  d*L <= x <= d*U
```

(Actually two constraints).

This is sometimes called a **semi-continuous variable**. Some solvers and modeling tools support this directly as a variable type, but in others, like PuLP, you need to use a binary variable to model this.

Comment: Can you suggest some solver that supports variable types ..

Comment: Most or all commercial MIP solvers support semi continuous variables directly.